# Dependency inject IPrincipal into a DBContext in separate assembly in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get details about the current user in my DBContext so that I can store a `CreatedByUserId` and `ModifiedByUserId` when a record is updated.

What I'm finding is that the IPrincipal instance injected is valid for the controllers, but is null when injected into my DB Context, which is in a separate assembly.

I'm doing the injection with Autofac as follows:

```
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User).As<IPrincipal>().InstancePerRequest();

builder.Register<AppDbContext>(c => new AppDbContext(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IPrincipal>())).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

My controller constructors look like this, and `user` will be valid here as expected:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ProductsController(IProductService productService, IPrincipal userPrincipal)
    {
        var user = userPrincipal;
        _productService = productService;
    }
```

My DBContext constructor looks like this and `user` will be null here:

```
public partial class AppDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IAppDbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(IPrincipal principal)
        : this("Name=SqlConnection", principal)
    {
        var user = principal;
    }
```

The controller code is called before the DB Context code, so it's not a timing issue, so I'm guessing the issue here is that the DB Context code is running on a different thread to the controller with different identity maybe?

If I use this code to get the identity in my DB context I can successfully get the user:

```
var user = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

But it seems like I might run into issues getting the user in two different ways in the same app, and I'd need to figure out a way to make the DI return HTTPContext's user to the web project and the thread's principal to another assembly, all of which smacks of being the wrong solution?

Can anyone help me understand exactly why I'm seeing the behaviour above and advise on the best way to get the principal in the different assemblies of an mvc app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue here turns out to be that I'm using the wrong Dependency Resolver when setting up the DB Context in this line:

```
builder.Register<AppDbContext>(c => new AppDbContext(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IPrincipal>())).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

`GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` is giving me the SignalR resolver rather than MVC's resolver.  Removing the GlobalHost bit then gives me the `System.Web.MVC.DependencyResolver` instead and then I can use that to get the IPrincipal as follows:

```
builder.Register<AppDbContext>(c => new AppDbContext(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPrincipal>())).InstancePerRequest();
```